# JSON array from $http.GET returning undefined even though it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs, http-get

Here is my code:

```
function getLineGraphData(unit, startTs, endTs, startState, endState){
points = [];
console.log('/file/tsDataPoints/'+unit+"?startDate="+startTs+"&endDate="+endTs+"&startState="+startState+"&endState="+endState);
$http.get('/file/tsDataPoints/'+unit+"?startDate="+startTs+"&endDate="+endTs+"&startState="+startState+"&endState="+endState).success(function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        points.push({x:getBasicTimeFromEpoch(data[i].ts), y:data[i].data});
    }
  return points;
  });
}

function fileStateLineGraph(unit, startTs, endTs){
getLineGraphData(unit, startTs, endTs, 1, 2);

console.log(getLineGraphData(unit, startTs, endTs, 1, 2));
var dp1= getLineGraphData(unit, startTs, endTs, 1, 2);
var dp2= getLineGraphData(unit, startTs, endTs, 2,3);
var dp3 = getLineGraphData(unit, startTs, endTs, 3,4);
console.log(dp1);
console.log(dp2);
console.log(dp3);
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    title: {
      text: "Click on legend items to hide/unhide dataseries"
    },
    legend: {
        cursor: "pointer",
        itemclick: function (e) {
            if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                e.dataSeries.visible = false;
            } else {
                e.dataSeries.visible = true;
            }
            chart.render();
        }
    },
    data: [{
      //axisYType:"secondary",
        showInLegend: true,
        type: "line",
        dataPoints: dp1
    }, {
        showInLegend: true,
        type: "line",
        dataPoints: dp2
    }, {
        showInLegend: true,
        type: "line",
        dataPoints: dp3
         }]
  });
  chart.render();
}
fileStateLineGraph("day",1404000000, 1406000000)
```

When I run the console.logs just display "undefined."  I'm wondering if it is because the function is running before the JSON call is completed, but I've never encountered an error like this.

Comment: Are you using AngularJS?  Where does `$http` come from?

Comment: @ScottRippey yes, I am using AngularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `getLineGraphData` function does not have a return value.  Second, it's running asynchronously, so you must wait for the `success` handler before you can access the `points` data.

So first, you must add a `return` statement: `return $http.get(...`.  This will return a Promise.

Second, to get access to `points`, you must use `promise.then(function(points) { ... })`.  Within the `then` function, you have access to the data.

Now, if you rely on multiple sets of points, you have to wait for them ALL to finish.  [You can use `$q.all(...)` as follows](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

```
$q.all({
    dp1: getLineGraphData(unit, startTs, endTs, 1,2),
    dp2: getLineGraphData(unit, startTs, endTs, 2,3),
    dp3: getLineGraphData(unit, startTs, endTs, 3,4)
}).then(function(dataPoints) {
    var dp1 = dataPoints.dp1, dp2 = dataPoints.dp2, dp3 = dataPoints.dp3;
    ... Create your chart ...
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how to use $q.all?  I don't quite understand how I'm supposed to use it

Comment: Sure :) When you have a Promise, you use `.then(callback)` (same as `.success(...)`) to access the results.  In your example, you have multiple promises.  So, `$q.all()` is a utility method that lets all the promises run in parallel, and when they're ALL finished, it'll execute your callback, with all the data.  You can give `$q.all(...)` either an object (`{key: promise1}`) or an array (`[promise1, promise2]`), and the results will be in the same format (either `{key: data1}` or `[data1, data2]`).  You should read up on Promises if you can, they're awesome!

Answer (score 1):

in getLineGraphData - you return points from the success callback of $http.get. This doesn't mean that it is returned from getLineGraphData. $http.get returns a promise and that is what you should return from the function. Then put a success callback on the promise and populate dp1 and so on..

```
 function getLineGraphData(unit, startTs, endTs, startState, endState){
    points = [];
    console.log('/file/tsDataPoints/'+unit+"?startDate="+startTs+"&endDate="+endTs+"&startState="+startState+"&endState="+endState);
    return $http.get('/file/tsDataPoints/'+unit+"?startDate="+startTs+"&endDate="+endTs+"&startState="+startState+"&endState="+endState);
 }

var dp1 = [];
getLineGraphData(unit, startTs, endTs, 1, 2).success(function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        dp1.push({x:getBasicTimeFromEpoch(data[i].ts), y:data[i].data});
    }
    console.log(dp1);
  });
```

dp1 should be printed ok.